# How to parse column values and its href with selenuim

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im new with selenium and parsing data from the website.
The problem is: i have website table with such HTML code:

```html
<table width="580" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="#ffffff" id="restab">
 <tbody>
   <tr align="center" valign="middle">
     <td width="40" bgcolor="#555555"><font color="#ffffff">№</font></td>
     <td width="350" bgcolor="#555555"><font color="#ffffff">Название организации</font></td>
     <td width="100" bgcolor="#555555"><font color="#ffffff">Город</font></td>
     <td width="60" bgcolor="#555555"><span title="Число публикаций данной организации на eLibrary.Ru"><font color="#ffffff">Публ.</font></span></td><td width="30" bgcolor="#555555"><span title="Число ссылок на публикации организации"><font color="#ffffff">Цит.</font></span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr valign="middle" bgcolor="#f5f5f5" id="a18098">
     <td align="center"><font color="#00008f">1</font></td>
     <td align="left"><font color="#00008f"><a href="org_about.asp?orgsid=18098">
"Академия информатизации образования" по Ленинградской области</a></font></td> 
     <td align="center"><font color="#00008f">Гатчина</font></td>
     <td align="right"><font color="#00008f">0<img src="/pic/1pix.gif" hspace="16"></font></td>
     <td align="center"><font color="#00008f">0</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr valign="middle" bgcolor="#f5f5f5" id="a17954">
     <td align="center"><font color="#00008f">2</font></td>
     <td align="left"><font color="#00008f"><a href="org_about.asp?orgsid=17954">
"Академия талантов" Санкт-Петербурга</a></font></td> 
     <td align="center"><font color="#00008f">Санкт-Петербург</font></td>
     <td align="right"><font color="#00008f"><a href="org_items.asp?orgsid=17954" title="Список статей данной организации на eLibrary.Ru">3</a><a href="org_profile.asp?id=17954" title="Анализ публикационной активности организации"><img src="/pic/stat.gif" width="12" height="13" hspace="10" border="0"></a></font></td>
     <td align="center"><font color="#00008f">0</font></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and i need to get all this table values and href's of each value in left td

I tried to use `Xpath`, but it writes some error, how to do it better?
In conclusion i need to get `dataframe` with table values + extra column with href of left column

Answer (score 0):

First try to use pandas.read_html().  See code example below.

If that doesn't work, then use use right-click menu on browser such as Mozilla Firefox (Inspect Element) or Google Chrome (Developer Tools) to find the CSS or Xpath.  Then feed the CSS or Xpath into Selenium.

Another useful tool for finding complicated CSS/Xpath is the Inspector Gadget browser plug-in.

```py
import pandas as pd

# this is the website you want to read ... table with "Minimum Level for Adult Cats"
str_url = 'http://www.felinecrf.org/catfood_data_how_to_use.htm'

# use pandas.read_html()
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html
list_df = pd.read_html(str_url, match='DMA')

print('Number of dataframes on the page: ', len(list_df))
print()

for idx, each_df in enumerate(list_df):
    print(f'Show dataframe number {idx}:')
    print(each_df.head())
    print()

# use table 2 on the page
df_target = list_df[2]

# create column headers
# https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_rename_column_headers/
header_row = df_target.iloc[0]

# Replace the dataframe with a new one which does not contain the first row
df_target = df_target[1:]

# Rename the dataframe's column values with the header variable
df_target.columns = header_row

print(df_target.head())
```